# Proof Verification: An isometry of surfaces composite with parametrization generates the same coeficients of first fundamental form

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification

I trying to proof the do Carmo exercise 2 section 4-2:

> Proof the following "converse" of Prop. 1: Let $\varphi:S \to \overline{S}$ be an isometry and $X: U \to S$ a parametrization at $p \in S$ then $\overline{X} = \varphi \circ X$ is a parametrization at $\varphi(p)$ and $E = \overline{E}$, $F = \overline{F}$, $G = \overline{G}$.

My approach is:

Since $\varphi$ is an isometry from $S$ to $\overline{S}$, it is also a differomorphism thus $\overline{X} = \varphi \circ X$ is a local parametrization of $\overline{S}$ around $\varphi(p)$.

Let $(u_0, v_0) \in U$ and $q = X(u_0,v_0)$. Let $\alpha$ the curve with $v=v_0$ constant, then $\alpha'(t) = X_u(t,v_0)$, so by definition
$$\mathrm{d} \varphi_q (X_u(u_0,v_0)) = (\varphi \circ \alpha)'(t_0).$$
On the other hand, since $\alpha(u) = X(u,v_0)$ we have that
$$(\varphi \circ \alpha)(u) = \varphi(\alpha(u)) = \varphi(X(u,v_0)) = (\varphi \circ X)(u,v_0) = \overline{X}(u,v_0)$$
Taking the differential we have that $(\varphi \circ \alpha)'(t) = \overline{X}_u(t,v_0)$, as $v_0$ is arbitrary we proof that $(\varphi \circ \alpha)' = \overline{X}_u=\mathrm{d} \varphi_q (X_u)$.

Now, by hipotesis, $\varphi$ is an isometry, so
$$\overline{E}(u,v) = \langle \overline{X}_u(u,v), \overline{X}_u(u,v) \rangle = \langle \mathrm{d} \varphi_q (X_u(u,v)), \mathrm{d} \varphi_q (X_u(u,v)) \rangle = \langle X_u(u,v), X_u(u,v) \rangle= E(u,v).$$

The same way we get that $\overline{F}=F$ and $\overline{G}=G$.

---

PS: I edited the answer following Ted Shifrin's guidelines, to which I am very grateful.

Comment: The idea is right, but the first expression after $\bar E = $ is just wrong.

Comment: I change the $\overline{X}$ to $\overline{X}_u$, digitation error. Is it? Thanks :)

Comment: For consistency, you should write $E(u,v_0)$, and then of course say $v_0$ is arbitrary. I wouldn't actually bother with fixing $v_0$ in that argument. It's true for arbitrary $u,v$, but just make your notation consistent.